# Performance of find() vs. for loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, loops

I've got a large (4000 values) set of unsorted, normally distributed points. I'm taking each of these data points into bins whose limits are in the BinLimit array. Then I'm tabulating the number of values in each bin.

X is the array of raw data, and N is the number of data points. The number of bins desired (TotalBins) is specified by the user.

Method #1

```
for i=1:TotalBins
    Freq(i) = length(find(X >= BinLimit(j) & X <= BinLimit(j+1)));
    j = j + 1;
end
```

Method #2:

```
sort(X);

for i=1:N
    if (X(i) >= BinLimit(j) && X(i) <= BinLimit(j+1))
        Freq(j) = freq(j) + 1;
    elseif (j < TotalBins)
        Freq(j+1) = freq(j+1) + 1;
        j = j + 1;
    end
end
```

Now, I know that the first solution is slower - for normal values of Total Bins (25-50) it's about 8 times slower but I'm wondering if there's a faster, more efficient solution than what I'm doing in Method #2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html).

> N = HISTC(X,EDGES), for vector X,
>   counts the number of values in X that
>   fall between the elements in the EDGES
>   vector (which must contain
>   monotonically non-decreasing values). 
>   N is a LENGTH(EDGES) vector containing
>   these counts.
>
> N(k) will count the
>   value X(i) if EDGES(k) <= X(i) <
>   EDGES(k+1).  The last bin will count
>   any values of X that match EDGES(end).
>   Values outside the values in EDGES are
>   not counted.  Use -inf and inf in
>   EDGES to include all non-NaN values.

E.g.

```
BinLimit = sort(rand(50,1));
X = rand(4000,1);
Freq = histc(X,BinLimit);
```

### For fun:

```
%%# Generating data
X = rand(1000000,1);
BinLimit = sort(rand(50,1));

%%# OP's method
disp('Method #1');
disp('=========');
tic;
j =1;
TotalBins = numel(BinLimit)-1;
for i=1:TotalBins
    Freq(i) = length(find(X >= BinLimit(j) & X <= BinLimit(j+1)));
    j = j + 1;
end
toc

%%# histc
disp('histc');
disp('=====');
tic;
histc(X,BinLimit);
toc

%%# My method
disp('Alternative');
disp('===========');
tic;
TotalBins = numel(BinLimit)-1;
Freq = zeros(TotalBins,1);
for i = 1:TotalBins
    Freq(i) = sum(X >= BinLimit(i) & X <= BinLimit(i+1));
end
toc
```

After a few runs to warm it up:

```
Method #1
=========
Elapsed time is 0.803120 seconds.
histc
=====
Elapsed time is 0.030633 seconds.
Alternative
===========
Elapsed time is 0.704808 seconds.
```

Comment: :(

Tested histc, and it's 1.4 times faster than what I did.

Comment: I'd still like to see a solution that bests mine in terms of code logic.

Comment: @Radu: Reinvent the wheel :) ? MATLAB's a lot about knowing the right routines and learning how to vectorize (and both are related), so ....

Comment: @Jacob, that's awesome. Faster and the code is a lot simpler! Thanks.

Comment: Picked as answer because it beats the other options although I do like Amro's solution. Thanks!

Comment: Histc is probably the fastest way to do it, but there is a loop structure that performs only ~25% worse than histc. Might reinventing the wheel, but still shows that matlab loops are not all that bad..

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using HISTC, here's a vectorized one-line solution:

```
X = randn(4000,1);                %# column vector
BinLimits = linspace(-4,4,10);    %# row vector

Freq = sum( bsxfun(@ge, X, BinLimits(1:end-1)) & bsxfun(@le, X, BinLimits(2:end)) )
```

Note that its not *space*-efficient though, as it create a matrix of size:
`length(X) by length(BinLimits)-1`

Comment: @Jacob: Note that `BinLimits` is a row vector, while `X` is a column vector

Comment: @Amro: Tested with my numbers and it seems like it's missing out the largest and smallest values. For one repetition it's about twice as slow as my solution but I can't argue with 1 liners.

Comment: @Radu: like I mentioned in the end, you need to test for the equality on one of the two sides, I'm just too lazy to figure out which ;)

Comment: @Radu: It turns out you need to do both sides. I edited the answer above

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an error when you check whether X belongs to a bin. You might get multiple bins for X values that fall onto the BinLimits.

```
X >= BinLimit(j) & X <= BinLimit(j+1)
```

Anyway, since you asked for a loop solution, here is one which performs better than your Method 2.

```
j=1;
i=1;
while i<=N
    while i<=N && X(i)<=BinLimit(j+1)
        i=i+1;
    end
    Freq(j) = i-1;
    j = j+1;
end
Freq=diff([0 Freq]);
```

It requires X to be sorted, as in your code. Below are timings for all the discussed methods for a sorted X array (histc also works faster for sorted X so it is a fair comparison):

```
Sort
===========
Elapsed time is 0.019205 seconds.
Method #1
=========
Elapsed time is 0.209979 seconds.
histc
=====
Elapsed time is 0.009595 seconds.
Alternative
===========
Elapsed time is 0.228400 seconds.
Method 2
===========
Elapsed time is 0.025400 seconds.
my method
===========
Elapsed time is 0.011920 seconds.
bsxfun by Amro
===========
Elapsed time is 0.179937 seconds.
```

As you see, this loop structure performs almost as well as histc (25% worse).

That was for sorted X (sorting time is given in the result above as well). Here is histc results for non-sorted arrays (the same X as above, permuted with a random permutation)

```
histc
=====
Elapsed time is 0.030367 seconds.
```

As you see, the time of sorting and histc on sorted arrays together is similar to running histc on unsorted array.